# Which short story involved people betting on turtle races with one man always winning?

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

Please help me identify this story. It was about a holiday resort where the residents bet on turtle races. One man won every race he bet on. As the story progressed, it appeared that he could see the future clearly.

What made this story interesting (and why I'd like to read it again) is that this turned out to be a curse, rather than a blessing. I can't remember why but somehow this impacted his free will.

This was in a sci-fi short story collection book, which started with "[Beggars in Spain](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beggars_in_Spain)".

I'd love to read it again so any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Is the question really a story identification question? If my answer turns out to be right, I'm tempted to close this question as too basic, since it was a simple bibliographic lookup. On the other hand, this can be search fodder for people looking for the same story who hadn't associated it with *Beggars in Spain*.

Comment: @Giles - I Googled it but didn't find it, so for me it wasn't too basic. Maybe you're just smarter than me?!

Comment: Reminds me of a "short-short" I read a *long* time ago in IASFM...where people would bet on their various alien pets in races.  One man, named Sloan, had an apparently immobile rock-like alien named "Teddy".  Someone decided to wager on it, and though he was laughed at, he won the wager when "Teddy" was discovered to have powers of teleportation, and zipped to the end.  Onlookers were told that this should have been obvious as "everyone knows that Slone's Teddy wins the race."

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can [browse the publications of *Beggars in Spain* on ISFDB](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/pl.cgi?TYBSF9) (I assume you mean the novella version). Glancing at the lists of titles, I suspect the story is [*A Tip on a Turtle*](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?53228) by [Robert Silverberg](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Robert_Silverberg).

> *Depressed and lonely after an ugly divorce, Denise goes to Jamaica to
> get her groove back. The hotel where she stays stages sea turtle races
> daily, and given the nature of the turtles, it's a completely random
> event. The turtles have no inclination to go one direction over
> another, so you can never tell which turtle will wander to the finish
> line first. But there's a tall, handsome man who always wins his bets.*

The collection is either [*Best New SF 6*](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/pl.cgi?BSTNWSFTHB1992) or [*The Year's Best Science Fiction 9*](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/pl.cgi?TYBSF9).